# Beautiful property of every single circunscribed polygon ever

Tags: geometry, polygons

Show that in any circumscribed polygon, there exist three sides which could form a triangle.

Been on it for a while starting with quadrilaterals and trying to connect some properties and proved for quadrilaterals. How to prove the general case.

Comment: What does that even mean? You spent more time explaining that you had already proved it for quadrilaterals than you spent explaining what it is you want proved.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: If I interpret correctly, his question is that given any polygon such that it circumscribes a circle, we can choose 3 distinct sides of the polygon such that their lengths are side lengths of some (non-degenerate) triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim follows immediately from taking the longest side and the two sides next to it, by using the basic property that the two tangent line segments from a point to a circle are of the same length.

[My original answer below was due to my misunderstanding of "circumscribed".]

I have proven that your proof for quadrilaterals is wrong, and hence your property is too beautiful to be true. Let $ABCD$ be a trapezium such that $AD \parallel CD$ and $(\overline{AB},\overline{CD},\overline{BC},\overline{AD}) = (9,6,2,2)$. Clearly $ABCD$ exists and is cyclic, but no three of its sides can be arranged to form a triangle.

Comment: I think "circumscribed polygon" means that we can inscribe circle in the polygon.

Comment: @Wojowu: That would not be a circumscribed polygon but rather an inscribed polygon (or circumscribing polygon).

Comment: Google supports my claim that "circumscribed" polygon lies outside the circle and the sides are tangent to its boundary.

Comment: @Wojowu: Alright I must take back my claim. Though I'm appalled at the terminology, since it is contrary to the English meaning of the past participle of "circumscribe".